# Unfortunately, AppName has stopped after click button

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I login and input Message in Edittext .but when I click send button, an application show  Webview popup  for about few minutes before to show message "Unfortunately, AppName has stopped."

WebView popup like Webview login popup on facebook

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static Facebook facebook = new Facebook("apikey");
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
String token;
Button login;
Button send;
EditText msg;
TextView onoff;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.postapp);
    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
    onoff = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.onoff);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            facebook.authorize(MainActivity.this, new String[]{"publish_stream"}, new DialogListener(){

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    onoff.setText("On");
                    token =values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    Log.d("FACEBOOK ERROR","FB ERROR. MSG: "+e.getMessage()+", CAUSE: "+e.getCause());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR","AUTH ERROR. MSG: "+e.getMessage()+", CAUSE: "+e.getCause());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d("CANCELLED","AUTH CANCELLED");
                }
            });

        }
    });

    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateStatus(token);
        }
    });
}

public void updateStatus(String accessToken){
    try {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message",msg.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN,accessToken);
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed",bundle,"POST");
        Log.d("UPDATE RESPONSE",""+response);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("MALFORMED URL",""+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOEX",""+e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

and postapp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign-in" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onoff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="off"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In LogCat when Click Send

```
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at  android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:193)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:777)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at facebook.appwall.MainActivity.updateStatus(MainActivity.java:84)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at facebook.appwall.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-05 05:08:57.376: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's not stopped without reasons... Read logcat log

Comment: What's the logcat say? What's your webview code?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do Network Operation on Main UI Thread in current code. so avoid hanging of UI and Crashing of Application  implement your code using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

put all facebook network operation code inside `doInBackground` and all code for updating UI stuff inside `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask` to avoid **"Unfortunately, AppName has stopped."** message

Answer (score 0):

You can add these line of code before authorize method

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your App beyond the Honeycomb.
it will not show this exception in lower versions below 3.0 try it on 2.2 or 2.3 it will work.
[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) will be helpful to you.